# Is there is a property to remove the dots from the ul element inside the flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, html-lists

How to remove the dots from the `[ ul ]` element, I used the `{ text-decoration: none;}` property and it worked. However when I set the container to `{ display: flex; }` it would appear again.

```
.header ul {
    text-decoration: none ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--main-background-color) ;
    display: flex;
    padding: var(--main-padding);
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `list-style: none;`

```css
.container ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <ul>
    <li>this</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>an Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can remove bullet's

```
ul{list-style-type:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

### This Might Be A Complete Solution For Your Question

```
.header ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
        
.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--main-background-color) ;
    display: flex;
    padding: var(--main-padding);
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: @Ahmed Modther if you find my answer so you can mark it correct so others can get helped too..

Answer (score 0):

```
    ul{
`        list-style-type:none;
     }
```